# How to change the background color with a button?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

How do I change the color of the background randomly with a button press in Android studio?

Here is my code:

```
public class partymodus extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_partymodus);

    final TextView aufgabe=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_aufgabe);
    final Button next =  (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_next);

    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Perform action on click
            String[] aufgaben = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.name);
            Random rand = new Random();
            int n = rand.nextInt(aufgaben.length - 0) + 0;
            aufgabe.setText(aufgaben[n]);

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Google answered the same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34091696/how-to-change-background-color-when-i-click-a-button

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change Background color when i click a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34091696/how-to-change-background-color-when-i-click-a-button)

Answer (score 2):

You have to add an `ActionListener` to your button and override the method:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
    ...//code that reacts to the action... 
}
```

And sorry for my english i'm beginner

Answer (score 0):

As an un-profession to answer your question, you have to digging out what is jave graphic design pattern is before goes in official API,
Here is a link to search the **JFrame** or **Java.awt.Graphic**, [[1]](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/)

it't where you start to build the components on the graphic,since you are building with a button component, I may suggest you looking the Inherit or father interface of **JFrame**, and another Containers

Answer (score 0):

```
MyActivity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()       {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

MyActivity.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.RED));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add `view_name.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));`
line to set background color

this is my code:

```
   mButton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mHomeLl.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
        }
    });
```